# How can I open all files from many folders in one window?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have many folders with many images in each one. I want to open a new file explorer window with all the images from all folders. Here is a screenshot :

[image: Folders]

In each folder there are many images I want to open a new window of file explorer that will contain all the images from all folders so I can browse them easy instead entering and exit each folder.

Comment: My suggestion is to use Everything (https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/)

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me that you want to create a new folder with all the images from many other folders. I'm more used to linux and I haven't tested it (I don't have a Windows machine available right now to test it on), but this script should work.

`folder1` is the folder in the screenshot above (showing all the other folders).

`folder2` is the folder all the images should end up in. I assume here that folder2 is in the same folder as folder1.

Replace `jpg` with whatever the file extension of all the images is.

```
cd folder1
copy *\*.jpg ..\folder2
```

Comment: hes no asking to move or copy, just to view